Is it possible to define @keyfames percentage based on css variable?
I've got an animation that depends on the number of characters
It works fine with 20 characters:


const text = '20 characters length'

const speed = 0.1

const $container = document.querySelector('.wave')

$container.style.setProperty('--duration', `${speed * text.length}s`)

for (const [index, char] of Object.entries([...text])) {
  const $el = document.createElement('span')
  $el.innerHTML = char === ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : char
  $el.style.setProperty('--delay', `${index * speed}s`)
  $container.appendChild($el)
}
div>* {
  animation: anim var(--duration) step-start var(--delay) infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%, 100% {
    translate: 0;
  }
  5% {
    translate: 0 -5px;
  }
}
<div class="wave"></div>



but only because 5% is the same as 1/20
If I change text length it's going too fast


const text = '10 char...'

const speed = 0.1

const $container = document.querySelector('.wave')

$container.style.setProperty('--duration', `${speed * text.length}s`)

for (const [index, char] of Object.entries([...text])) {
  const $el = document.createElement('span')
  $el.innerHTML = char === ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : char
  $el.style.setProperty('--delay', `${index * speed}s`)
  $container.appendChild($el)
}
div>* {
  animation: anim var(--duration) step-start var(--delay) infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%, 100% {
    translate: 0;
  }
  5% {
    translate: 0 -5px;
  }
}
<div class="wave"></div>



I would need to change 5% to 10% in @keyframes


const text = '10 char...'

const speed = 0.1

const $container = document.querySelector('.wave')

$container.style.setProperty('--duration', `${speed * text.length}s`)

for (const [index, char] of Object.entries([...text])) {
  const $el = document.createElement('span')
  $el.innerHTML = char === ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : char
  $el.style.setProperty('--delay', `${index * speed}s`)
  $container.appendChild($el)
}
div>* {
  animation: anim var(--duration) step-start var(--delay) infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%, 100% {
    translate: 0;
  }
  10% {
    translate: 0 -5px;
  }
}
<div class="wave"></div>



I can change duration and delay using css variables.
Can I do the same with @keyframes list?

Pretty sure you can't do that with keyframe percentage steps, but you can define offsets dynamically using the Web Animations API.

You will not be able to set a css variable to the keyframe of the animation. So use the Web Animations API.
I tried to reproduce your animation and it seems to work. The first is the original css animation, and below with the help of js:


const anim = (el, options) => {
  options = {
    ...{
      speed: 0.1,
      translateY: '-5px',
    },
    ...options,
  };
  const text = el.dataset.text || '';
  const offset = 100 / text.length / 100;
  const duration = options.speed * text.length * 1000;

  for (const [index, chr] of Object.entries([...text])) {
    const delay = (index - 1) * options.speed * 1000;
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = chr === ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : chr;
    el.appendChild(span);
    span.animate(
      [
        { translate: '0 0', offset: offset - 0.0001 },
        { translate: `0 ${options.translateY}`, offset: offset },
        { translate: `0 ${options.translateY}`, offset: offset * 2 - 0.0001 },
        { translate: '0 0', offset: offset * 2 },
      ],
      {
        duration: duration,
        delay: delay,
        iterations: Infinity,
      },
    );
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll('.wave').forEach(wave => anim(wave));
.wave,
.wave-css {
  span {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.wave-css span {
  animation: anim var(--duration) step-start var(--delay) infinite;
}

@keyframes anim {
  5% {
    translate: 0 -5px;
  }
}

.waves {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
  gap: 2px 8px;
}
<div class="waves">
  <span>wave css:</span>
  <div class="wave-css" style="--duration: 2s;"><span style="--delay: 0s;">2</span><span style="--delay: 0.1s;">0</span><span style="--delay: 0.2s;">&nbsp;</span><span style="--delay: 0.30000000000000004s;">c</span><span style="--delay: 0.4s;">h</span><span style="--delay: 0.5s;">a</span><span style="--delay: 0.6000000000000001s;">r</span><span style="--delay: 0.7000000000000001s;">a</span><span style="--delay: 0.8s;">c</span><span style="--delay: 0.9s;">t</span><span style="--delay: 1s;">e</span><span style="--delay: 1.1s;">r</span><span style="--delay: 1.2000000000000002s;">s</span><span style="--delay: 1.3s;">&nbsp;</span><span style="--delay: 1.4000000000000001s;">l</span><span style="--delay: 1.5s;">e</span><span style="--delay: 1.6s;">n</span><span style="--delay: 1.7000000000000002s;">g</span><span style="--delay: 1.8s;">t</span><span style="--delay: 1.9000000000000001s;">h</span></div>
  <span>wave js:</span>
  <div>
    <div class="wave" data-text="20 characters length"></div>
    <div class="wave" data-text="10 char..."></div>
  </div>
</div>



